# Make grid container 100% height of content

Tags: css, css-grid

**Goal**: sticky nav bar at top, followed by grid where last row of the grid maintains its natural height, but is at the bottom of the window if there's insufficient content to push it off screen.

**Problem**: I'm having issues getting my grid to be 100% of the height of the content, which is messing up my sticky nav bar (at least I think this is the issue). My content is coming from a headless CMS, and HTML is generated via NextJS. A page generally looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="__next">
            <header></header> // should be sticky
            <div> // wrapper, which I'm making a grid
                Somewhat arbitrary content from the CMS...
                <footer>Comes from the CMS also</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Styling the header like so basically worked:

```
header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However, when I got around to creating custom error pages, I realised that if there was insufficient content, the footer inside my grid wasn't at the bottom of the page. After some googling and experimenting, the solution seemed to be to make sure that the `html` and `body` both had `height: 100%; min-height: 100vh;`, and that, because there was only 1 row in the grid before the footer, I could do `grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;`, so the the first row would expand to fill the available space, and the footer would shrink to its proper size, but get pushed to the bottom.

So far, so good — that worked on the pages with little/no content. But, now I have a problem with regular pages (i.e., pages with more than one row, and/or sufficient content to be taller than `vh`.

As you can see in this snippet, the sticky nav bar is sticky for a while, but then stops being sticky. This appears to me to be because the grid container is not expanding to the height of all of its content.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

#__next {
  min-height: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  padding-left: calc(((100vw - 80rem) / 2) + (80rem / 12));
  padding-right: calc(((100vw - 80rem) / 2) + (80rem / 12));
  width: 100%;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 12;
  /* appearance only */
  padding: 6rem 0;
  background-color: #121212;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  /* grid-auto-rows: 1fr; */
  max-width: 80rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item-1 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 7;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 7;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.item-3 {
  grid-row: span 2 / span 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 7;
  grid-column-end: 12;
  height: 787px;
  background-color: #dedede;
}

.item-4 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 12;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="__next">
    <header>
      <nav><span>I'm in the header, and should stick. Scroll down to see it work for a while ... and then stop.</span></nav>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item-1">
        <h1>I'm at the bottom of my container.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="item-2">
        <p>I flow nicely after that, because I'm at the top</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-3">I'm an image</div>
      <section class="item-4">
        <p>I'm some more content.</p>
        <div style="height: 300px">Just taking up space</div>
      </section>
      <footer>I'm fancy, I'm a footer.</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;`, `grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;`, and `grid-auto-rows: auto;`, but to no avail.

How do I achieve my desired goal (i.e., footer inside grid at bottom of window when insufficient content; sticky nav bar, outside of grid)?

**Edit: NB:** Since I'm writing the NextJS, and control the CMS templates, I can move the footer out of the grid, if that helps at all.

Comment: If your sticky topbar has a fixed height, you could defined it in a variable, for example `--topbar-variable`. You can then use this variable also to set the height of the content, something like `.content { min-height: calc(100vh - var(--topbar-height)); }`

Comment: I think the problem is the other way: the content has arbitrary height, and is much more than `100vh`; I need to expand the .content, not shrink it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that structure of your html is a bit messy.

First things first. Make sure you need a sticky navbar. Usually navigation menus are `position: fixed`. The only reason I can imagine for sticky navbar is if you have 2 separate content bodies and you want to have navbar only for one of them or different navbar for the other.

Here is structure you want.

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.imitation-of-content {
  height: 2000px;
}

.scope-of-sticky-navbar {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content-without-navbar {
  background-color: green;
}


footer {
  flex: 0 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.scope-of-sticky-navbar, .content-without-navbar {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="scope-of-sticky-navbar">
    <header>Header stuff</header>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class="imitation-of-content">content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content-without-navbar">
    <div class="imitation-of-content">content2</div>
  </div>
  
  <footer>
    Footer stuff
  </footer>
  
</body>

</html>
```

`position: sticky` will just follow scrolling till the end of its parent element. Offset from top and bottom is regulated with top, bottom properties on sticky element and is relative to the parent element.

Avoid setting height of elements manually if their height changes depending on content. `height: 100%` is making your wrappers height 100% relative to its parent, which messes things up and makes it's children overflow. All you need is `min-height`. Let it figure out it's actual height on it's own.

Comment: Moving the footer out of the grid container, and changing the top level to flex column (along with removing the 100% heights) solved it. Re: the navbar, it's `sticky` instead of `fixed` so that it doesn't pop out of the DOM flow — no need to calculate funny paddings when the header may be of uncertain heigh, and more importantly, color matching for background gradients in the next section. Any reason not to use it?

Comment: Well as to if there are reasons to not use it, there are benefits and minuses to both. For example position sticky doesnt work if one of the parent elements has overflow:hidden if you will apply overflow:hidden to your body or html in future while showing a modal/popover, then your navbar will jump up back to its initial position which is unwanted behaviour. But yes unknown navbar height as you pointed out is for example benefit of position sticky that i didnt think about.